# Can't download Android source with Repo: "cannot initialize work tree for platform/build/blueprint"

Tags: git, android, sync

I'm trying to use `repo` to download the Android source as per [Google's instructions](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading). I've downloaded and initialized the Repo client and am now trying to update the working tree. After running `repo sync --force-broken`, all projects appear to be fetched correctly as console output reads `Fetching projects: 100% (733/733), done.` However, immediately after printing, that messsage, Repo appears to fail to sync the work tree, showing the following error:

```
Syncing work tree:   0% (2/733) (NOTE: newline inserted here for readability)
error: unable to create file pathtools/testdata/escapes/*: Invalid argument
fatal: cannot create directory at 'pathtools/testdata/escapes/**': Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo/main.py", line 547, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo/main.py", line 522, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo/main.py", line 184, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo\subcmds\sync.py", line 855, in Execute
    project.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, force_sync=opt.force_sync)
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo\project.py", line 1380, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync, submodules=submodules)
  File "D:\2019 Work\androidsrc\.repo\repo\project.py", line 2594, in _InitWorkTree
    raise GitError("cannot initialize work tree for " + self.name)
error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree for platform/build/blueprint
```

`repo --version` yields:

```
repo version v1.13.3
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
repo launcher version 1.25
       (from C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\repo)
git version 2.22.0.windows.1
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: any solutions did you got?

Comment: @RahulBaradia Still nothing, sorry. :/

Comment: any luck ??, did you get any workaround?

Comment: @Venky Nope, nothing, same issue.

Comment: @HewwoCraziness are you doing this on WSL or on a Linux Distro?

Comment: @Venky Same result on both Raspberry Pi 3 (with a massive swapfile) and MSYS2 on Windows 10.

Comment: I was able to get it going on a Linux Distro which has a ext4 system with 16GB of Swap, you might want to give it a try

Comment: @Venky same, literally allocated 64GB of swap, thanks anyway... what distro were you trying?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 , wasn't using it on raspberry pi though

Comment: @Venky Alright, thanks, will try in a VM later today

Answer (score 0):

cd into < build-root > (i.e. dir where bionic/, development/, device/, et.c are located) and try:

```
repo sync --force-sync build/blueprint
```

If facing same issues in multiple directories, try:

```
for subprj in $(repo status | grep ^project | cut -d ' ' -f2); 
do 
    repo sync --force-sync $subprj; 
done
```